# Calculate from lists and print the output as table

Tags: python, list, printing, sum

I'm new in the python.

I have the following lists:

hardware = ["motherboard", "cpu", "gpu"]

amount = [5, 8, 4, 6]

cost   = [210.0, 250.5, 360.8]

I want to print an output as you can see in txt file provided in the link below.

My try is following:

```
hardware = ["motherboard", "cpu", "gpu"]
amount = [5, 8, 4, 6]
cost   = [210.0, 250.5, 360.8]

product_cost = [a*b for a,b in zip(amount, cost)]
total = sum(product_cost)

titles = ['Hardware', 'Amount', 'Cost per item', 'Total cost per hardware']
data = [titles] + list(zip(hardware, amount, cost, product_cost))

for i, d in enumerate(data):
    line = ' '.join(str(x).ljust(12) for x in d)
    print(line)
    if i == 0:
        print(' ' * len(line))

print('\n' "Total cost: " + str(total))
```

But the output I get is not the desired one as you can see in txt file

I attach the txt file. Here is the link of txt:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vANzMk9z2cxTWJRlwH3AkudN_jlG3iah

Can you help me to get the desired result.

Comment: SInce your problem is with formatting, you could use any module which makes neat tables. But still wait, someone else could help.

Comment: columns have different width so first you should get `len()` for all elements in column and get `max()` length. And use `ljust()` only in first column. Other columns need `rjust()`. OR find modules for this - like [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/)

Answer (score 0):

This should match your desired result. You can adjust the spacing in the table for yourself as you want.

```
hardware = ["motherboard", "cpu", "gpu"]
amount = [5, 8, 4, 6]
cost   = [210.0, 250.5, 360.8]

product_cost = [a*b for a,b in zip(amount, cost)]
total = sum(product_cost)

titles = ['Hardware', 'Amount', 'Cost per item', 'Total cost per hardware']
data = [titles] + list(zip(hardware, amount, cost, product_cost))

for i in range(len(data)):
    if i == 0:
      print('{:<15s}{:>10s}{:>20s}{:>30s}'.format(data[i][0],data[i][1],data[i][2],data[i][3]))
      print()
    else:
      print('{:<15s}{:>10d}{:>20.2f}{:>30.2f}'.format(data[i][0],data[i][1],data[i][2],data[i][3]))

print('\n' "Total cost: %.2f" % (total))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you have to convert rows to columns and calculate max lenght in every column

```
rows = [titles] + list(zip(hardware, amount, cost, product_cost))

columns = list(zip(*rows))

lengths = [max([len(str(x)) for x in col]) for col in columns]
```

Next you have to every element in row display separatelly because first column need `ljust` and other columns need `rjust` - and all of them need different value from `lenghts`

Because text in first column is longer then title so I used extra `elif` for second column. Make it more universal would need more work.

```
hardware = ["motherboard", "cpu", "gpu"]
amount = [5, 8, 4, 6]
cost   = [210.0, 250.5, 360.8]
product_cost = [a*b for a,b in zip(amount, cost)]

total = sum(product_cost)

titles = ['Hardware', 'Amount', 'Cost per item', 'Total cost per hardware']

rows = [titles] + list(zip(hardware, amount, cost, product_cost))

columns = list(zip(*rows))
lengths = [max([len(str(x)) for x in col]) for col in columns]
#print(lengths)

for y, row in enumerate(rows):
    for x, item in enumerate(row): 
        l = lengths[x]
        if x == 0:
            print(str(item).ljust(l), end='')
        elif x == 1:
            print(str(item).rjust(l+2), end='')
        else:
            print(str(item).rjust(l+5), end='')
    print()
    if y == 0:
        print()

print('\nTotal cost: {:.2f}'.format(total))
```

Result

```
Hardware     Amount     Cost per item     Total cost per hardware

motherboard       5             210.0                      1050.0
cpu               8             250.5                      2004.0
gpu               4             360.8                      1443.2

Total cost: 4497.20
```

---

**EDIT:** Similar with module [tabulate](https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate)

```
hardware = ["motherboard", "cpu", "gpu"]
amount = [5, 8, 4, 6]
cost   = [210.0, 250.5, 360.8]
product_cost = [a*b for a,b in zip(amount, cost)]
total = sum(product_cost)

titles = ['Hardware', 'Amount', 'Cost per item', 'Total cost per hardware']
rows = list(zip(hardware, amount, cost, product_cost))

import tabulate

print(tabulate.tabulate(rows, headers=titles, floatfmt=".1f"))

print('\nTotal cost: {:.2f}'.format(total))
```

Result:

```
Hardware       Amount    Cost per item    Total cost per hardware
-----------  --------  ---------------  -------------------------
motherboard         5            210.0                     1050.0
cpu                 8            250.5                     2004.0
gpu                 4            360.8                     1443.2

Total cost: 4497.20
```